# debate sobre um chat com os assuntos mais comentados

Tags: debate, suporte, novo-recurso, chat

acho que iria dar super certo. e com a questão de palestrante no chat ,**poderíamos escolher os melhores da comunidade STACKOOVERFLOW para palestrar ou melhor ainda uma live no propio site**.  
com os assuntos mais comentados do momentos e os mais acessados como se fosse um evento sabe, tipo um aulão que poderíamos dar sujestao comentar e aprender sobre o assunto . 
ai iria aparecer uma notificação no seu perfil que tal horas haverar um evento sobre HTML ,CSS, javascript etc...

e uma questão a ser estudada e acredito que o índice de aprovação seria grande ,basta nois nos unir e agir de alguma maneira - sou novo aki mais tenho boas ideias e tarei aqui para ajudar e ser ajudado